# Function call inside function, not possible to verify via kotlin mockito

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockito

We need to verify how many times function `getTree()` was called inside `getFish()`.
But library don't recognize function call
`Wanted but not invoked: factory.getTree();`

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.kotlin.doReturn
import org.mockito.kotlin.mock
import org.mockito.kotlin.times
import org.mockito.kotlin.verify


class Testing {

    open class Factory {
        open fun getFish(): List<Int> {
            getTree()
            return listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
        }

        open fun getTree(): String {
            return "tree"
        }

    }


    @Test
    fun testFish() {
        val mockedFactory = mock<Factory> {
            on { getFish() } doReturn  listOf(5,6,7,8,9,10)
            on { getTree() } doReturn  "tree"
        }
        mockedFactory.getFish()

        verify(mockedFactory, times(1)).getTree()
    }


}
```

Successful verification how many times function was called inside function

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `getFish` is mocked. So it does not get called "really". As soon as `getFish` gets called, it immediately returns `listOf(5,6,7,8,9,10)` and *skips* its actual code logic.

I suggest to change testing strategy: do not mock factory at all if you want to test it. Since you are interested in executing real code, let it be real object.

```
class Testing {

    class Factory {
        fun getFish(): List<Int> {
            getTree()
            return listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
        }

        fun getTree(): String {
            return "tree"
        }
    }

    val factory = Factory()

    @Test
    fun testFish() {
        factory.getFish()
        verify(factory, times(1)).getTree()
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, that mocked object are usually used if the testing target keeps references to different entities. Those entities are mocked to return desired data and encapsulate their inner logic, letting the developer to test only the desired target while not worrying about other entities.